# multiple messages sync with tf

Tags: message-filters, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to write a callback where two topics and tf are synchronized.  For example I want to have an image, a pointcloud and tf at the same time.

I inspired from the piece of code below, which deals with one topic and tf. Does anybody know how to extend tf:MessageFilter to two or more topics?

Thanks

```
 tf::TransformListener tf_;
 tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> * tf_filter_;
 message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> cloud2_sub_;

//initialisation
cloud2_sub_.subscribe(n, "/kinect/rgb/points2", 10);
tf_filter_ = new tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>(cloud2_sub_, tf_, "/map", 10);
tf_filter_->registerCallback( boost::bind(&PointReader::pointCloudCallback, this, _1) );

//callback
void pointCloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& sensor_msg)
{
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12374/multiple-messages-sync-with-tf/) by [Akin](https://answers.ros.org/users/230/akin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tf::MessageFilter is based on the core [message_filter package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters) which can be used to do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0